# OWL Restrictions: Defining classes that depend on a concept hierarchy

Tags: owl, restriction

I have a hierarchy of `skos:Concept`s and want to define an `owl:Class` consisting of those individuals that are connected to a specific concept *or one of its narrower terms* through some property.
I managed to create an `owl:Restriction` that works for one specific concept, but not for a hierarchy of concepts:

```
# Concept hierarchy
concepts:Dance a skos:Concept .
concepts:FolkDance a skos:Concept ;
    skos:broaderTransitive concepts:Dance .
concepts:SquareDance a skos:Concept ;
    skos:broaderTransitive concepts:FolkDance .

# owl axioms
ex:Dance rdfs:subClassOf ex:Movement ;
    owl:equivalentClass [
        a owl:Restriction ;
        owl:onProperty ex:hasKindOfMovement ;
        owl:hasValue concepts:Dance
    ] .

# Assertions
ex:SomeInstance ex:hasKindOfMovement concepts:Dance .
```

The above correctly makes `ex:someInstance` an instance of `ex:Dance`. But how can I make `ex:anotherInstance` a member of `ex:Dance` if I have the assertion

```
ex:anotherInstance ex:hasKindOfMovement concepts:SquareDance
```

? I. e. where the individual in `owl:hasValue` is a transitively narrower concept than the one specified in the restriction.

This question seems similar to [OWL restrictions - defining classes that only contains properties with a specific property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110845/owl-restrictions-defining-classes-that-only-contains-properties-with-a-specifi) but I couldn't work it out from there... Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The problem here is that the SKOS semantics has nothing in common with the OWL semantics, i.e. `skos:broader` won't be used during OWL inference like it's done for `rdfs:subClassOf`

Comment: @AKSW Thanks for your note. Does that mean that there is no way to create an `owl:Class` such that class membership is restricted to `skos:Concept`s that are `skos:narrower` than a specific individual?

Comment: Well, first of all, you used `owl:hasValue concepts:Dance` which makes `concepts:Dance` an instance of `owl:NamedIndividual`, thus, even if `concepts:Dance` would be an `owl:Class` it wouldn't work. Using `owl:someValuesFrom concepts:Dance` instead would also not work as long as `concepts:SquareDance` isn't related to `concepts:Dance` via OWL subsumption hierarchy which in fact is not the case with the `skos:broader` property. Not sure if hijacking would work here, unfortunately I'm not that familiar with SKOS. Others here might know a solution besides using OWL only